# Addition of a column takes time in PySpark Dataframes

Tags: python, dataframe, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am currently trying to integrate PySpark and Cassandra and am having trouble optimising the code in order for it to execute faster.

```
from pyspark import SparkContext, SparkConf
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext, SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.functions import sum as _sum

def connect_cassandra():
    spark = SparkSession.builder \
      .appName('SparkCassandraApp') \
      .config('spark.cassandra.connection.host', 'localhost') \
      .config('spark.cassandra.connection.port', '9042') \
      .config('spark.cassandra.output.consistency.level','ONE') \
      .master('local[*]') \
      .getOrCreate()

    sqlContext = SQLContext(spark)
    return sqlContext

#--------THIS FUNCTION IS MY CONCERN ACTUALLY------------
def check_ip(ip, df):
    rows= df.filter("src_ip = '"+ip+"' or dst_ip = '"+ip+"'") \
            .agg(_sum('total').alias('data')) \
            .collect()

    print(rows[0][0])
#-----------------------------------------------------------

def load_df(sqlContext):

    df = sqlContext \
      .read \
      .format('org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra') \
      .options(table='acrs_app_data_usage', keyspace='acrs') \
      .load()

    return df

if __name__ == '__main__':
    lists = ['10.8.25.6', '10.8.24.10', '10.8.24.11', '10.8.20.1', '10.8.25.15', '10.8.25.10']
    sqlContext = connect_cassandra()
    df = load_df(sqlContext)
    for ip in lists:
        check_ip(ip, df)
```

The function `check_ip()` here takes an ip and a pre-loaded dataframe, the data-frame has 3 columns(`src_ip, dst_ip and total`) and around 250K rows ,as argument and then iterates through it's total-column adding them and returning the summed data grouped by the IP provided.

But when I execute the script, it takes atleast a second per IP to return the summed amount. And I have over 32K IPs for which the same has to happen. And the amount of time is a lot.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: Don't use loops.

Possible solution:

- Convert `lists` to dataframe.
- Inner Join `lists_df` twice with your dataframe, first on `ip == src_ip` and the second on `ip == dst_ip`
- Concatenate both with `unionAll`
- Finally use `groupBy("ip").agg(_sum("total"))`

This uses joins. So there is perhaps an even better solution out there.